# how to replace jquery to jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile, web, phonegap-plugins

I have built a web app and have used jquery
I want to use phone gap to make mobile app with my web app
do I need to change the loading of Jquery to Jquery mobile library only
or I need to change some functions ?

Comment: jQuery works on mobile, it's jquery-ui that usually makes the problems because touch events are different, but loading this library right after the jquery-ui file does the job. http://touchpunch.furf.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For using jquery-mobile you need jquery as dependency since its the core of Jquery-Mobile.